# How to configure eth0 in kali linux?

Tags: networking, kali-linux

How to configure eth0 in kali linux.
I've tried configuring eth0 through ifconfig command and it also worked but when I rebooted my computer the changes reverted back to there previous state.
Please help me out!
It's not show ipv4 under eth0 only showing ether that is mack address and ipv6.

Comment: Static or dynamic address?

Comment: Static but I need to configure it permanently not by ifconfig.

Comment: Is it still `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the network with the already-installed `ifupdown` package, which includes the `ifup` and `ifdown` tools. These tools read definitions from the `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration file and are at the heart of the `/etc/init.d/networking` init script that configures the network at boot time.

Each network device managed by `ifupdown` can be deconfigured at any time with `ifdown network-device`. You can then modify `/etc/network/interfaces` and bring the network back up (with the new configuration) with `ifup network-device`.

Let’s take a look at what we can put in ifupdown’s configuration file. There are two main directives: `auto network-device`, which tells ifupdown to automatically configure the network interface once it is available, and `iface network-device inet/inet6 type` to configure a given interface. For example, a plain DHCP configuration looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Note that the special configuration for the loopback device should always be present in this file. For a fixed IP address configuration, you have to provide more details such as the IP address, the network, and the IP of the gateway:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.3
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
network 192.168.0.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

For wireless interfaces, you must have the wpasupplicant package (included in Kali by default), which provides many `wpa-*` options that can be used in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Have a look at `/usr/share/doc/wpasupplicant/README.Debian.gz` for examples and explanations. The most common options are `wpa-ssid` (which defines the name of the wireless network to join) and `wpa-psk` (which defines the passphrase or the key protecting the network).
iface wlan0 inet dhcp

```
wpa-ssid MyNetWork
wpa-psk plaintextsecret
```

You can find more details [here](https://kali.training/topic/configuring-the-network/)

Comment: I have configured these configurations earlier but by setting up a static Ip address the BurpSuite which is an important tool in kali linux did not works and when I set up a DHCP network then it gives me a new ip every time by which I can't listen the backdoors which I made to listen on a specific IP.